# Only Given Name in Passport, How to apply Thai Pass without surname?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, thailand

I want to apply for ThaiPass for one my client,
he doesn't have any surname in his passport, just given name is there.
how to process without surname?

Comment: Which country issued his passport?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the international standard is to state 'FNU' for the first name (First Name Unknown), and the person's single name for the surname.

If you want to be certain (and I suggest that you do), Thai travel agents are typically very responsive and helpful.  They are easy to find.  Search for some on Facebook or Google.